# GraalVM TypeHint not included in reflect-config.json

Tags: java, bouncycastle, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

As mentioned above, when I try to include a Hint, Spring-AOT plugin (spring-aot:generate) is not detecting the annotation and the reflection is not included in the **reflect-config.json**

Here is the code where I use the annotation.

```
@TypeHint(
        typeNames = "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi",
        access= AccessBits.PUBLIC_CONSTRUCTORS | AccessBits.PUBLIC_METHODS
)
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Has this happened to anyone else?
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. It worked for me

```
@TypeHint(
    types = {RoutesDto.class, RouteDto.class, TrainJourney.class},
    access= {TypeAccess.PUBLIC_CONSTRUCTORS, TypeAccess.PUBLIC_METHODS}
)
```

Comment: The problem in my case was that I didn't import bouncycastle library in the pom.xml, and there were no packages with "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySp" this path, therefore AOT couldn't find it and didn't put it in the reflect-config.json